# Magento Customer Configuration set up Gender options

Tags: magento, configuration, registration

I'm trying to add optional fields to registration form Gender: with options Male, Female.

In Magento admin panel there is and option to do that. System > Configuration > Customer Configuration under Name and Address there is a field show gender. However when I set it to optional or required field with drop down shows up on the frontend but, there is nothing to choose from, drop down is is empty, there is no Male or Female options.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: have you added options for the attribute? (in the attribute's edit screen, the second tab, on the left)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reasons the attribute options are not present in your instance. To insert them manually run the following queries.
First you need to identify the gender attribute.

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'gender'
```

take the id of the resulted row. For me it's 18.

```
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_option` SET `attribute_id` = 18, `sort_order` = 0;
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_option` SET `attribute_id` = 18, `sort_order` = 1;
```

This will insert 2 options. for the attribute (replace 18 with the id you get from the first select).

Now these 2 inserted rows should have an autoincrement value for `option_id`. Take these 2 values and run the following queries. Let's say the value are `34` and `35`.

```
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_option_value` set `option_id` = 34, `store_id` = 0, `value` = 'Male';
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_option_value` set `option_id` = 35, `store_id` = 0, `value` = 'Female';
```

This will insert the option labels. Replace `34` and `35` with the values you get after the first set of inserts.

Clear the cache should be set.
Back-up your database just in case I'm wrong.

Comment: Hi Marius, can you help me? How we can translate it on backend? i tried add to csv file but it not working.